# html - <input type=button> and <button>

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, button, textarea

I'm trying to get a button value in my textarea which is working fine if I use `<button>` but if I use `<input type=button>` then it not works. Could you find out what is the problem?

**HTML**

```
<textarea id="txt-area" readonly></textarea>
<button class="buttons">1</button>
<button class="buttons">2</button>
<button class="buttons">3</button>
<button class="buttons">4</button>
<input type="button" class="buttons" value=" Test">
```

**JavaScript**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".buttons").click(function () {
        var cntrl = $(this).html();
        $("#txt-area").val(function (_, val) {
            return val + cntrl + ","
        });
    });
});
```

My code is also in this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cPYCV/26/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

BUTTONs have innerHTML but INPUTs don't. You need to check if the element's tag name is Input or Button

Check this updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gurvinder372/cPYCV/27/)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".buttons").click(function () {
        var cntrl = $(this).html();
        if ($(this)[0].nodeName == "INPUT" )
        {
                cntrl = $(this).attr( "value" );
        }
        $("#txt-area").val(function (_, val) {
            return val + cntrl + ","
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you, I'm new to this stuff and this was really helpful thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

For  you have to get value but not innerHTML.
So in your code it should be

```
var cntrl = $(this).html() || $(this).val();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 <textarea id="txt-area" readonly></textarea>
 <button class="buttons">1</button>
 <button class="buttons">2</button>
 <button class="buttons">3</button>
 <button class="buttons">4</button>
 <input type="button" class="buttons" value=" Test">

$(document).ready(function () {
$(".buttons").click(function () {
    var cntrl =  $(this).html();
    $("#txt-area").val(function (_, val) {
        return val + cntrl + ","
    });
});
});
```

this the above code you have posted in jsfiddle...

if you use    means you are giving values

Inseated of this `var cntrl =  $(this).html();` Use   `var cntrl =  $(this).val();`

working version has been updated below link

http://jsfiddle.net/cPYCV/32/

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `[<button>]`, then you should use `$('.class').text();`
In case you are using `[<input type="button">]`, then `$('.class').val();` would work fine.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".buttons").click(function () {
        var cntrl = $(this).html() || $(this).val();;
        $("#txt-area").val(function (_, val) {
            return val + cntrl + ","
        });
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea id="txt-area" readonly></textarea>
<button class="buttons">1</button>
<button class="buttons">2</button>
<button class="buttons">3</button>
<button class="buttons">4</button>
<input type="button" class="buttons" value="Test">
```

hope this help someone!